# Python: Unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' whilst using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I'm currently using lambda to make a tkinter button do two things after each other:

```
def classManip():    
    cManip = tk.Toplevel()
    cManip.title('Class Manipulator')
    cManip.minsize(400,100)
    cManip.maxsize(400,100)

    databaseEntry = ttk.Entry(cManip, width = 25)
    databaseEntry.place(relx = .5, rely = .375, anchor = "c")

    entrySubmit = ttk.Button(cManip, text = "Enter", width = 20, command = lambda : connectDatabase(databaseEntry.get()) & cManip.destroy())
    entrySubmit.place(relx = .5, rely = .625, anchor="c")
    cManip.mainloop()
```

this is the function from my main code; I have a button on my main tkinter window that has the command to run this function.
The connect databaseEntry function is form another file named databaseManip in a folder named scripts which I import using:

```
from scripts.databaseManip import connectDatabase
```

and the code within that file is:

```
import sqlite3, sys, os
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

#connects or creates database
def connectDatabase(name):
    name = str(name)
    screenWidth =  GetSystemMetrics (0)
    screenHeight =  GetSystemMetrics (1)

    if os.path.isfile("classDbFiles/" + name + ".db"):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("classDbFiles/" + name + ".db")
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(message="Connected to %s successfully" % (str(name + ".db")), title = "File Found")
    else:   
        conn = sqlite3.connect("classDbFiles/" + name + ".db")
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(message = "The database file %s was created and opened successfully" % (str(name + ".db")), title = "Success")
```

What I want for the program to do is to run the database function creating or opening the .db file and then to close the tkinter window afterwards and funnily enough it does actually work but it returns the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Dropbox\Computing Project\mainApp.py", line 52, in <lambda>
    entrySubmit = ttk.Button(cManip, text = "Enter", width = 20, command = lambda : connectDatabase(databaseEntry.get()) & cManip.destroy())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

I have searched for an answer but nothing seems to be for lambda so I'm lost. What's wrng with the code?

Comment: Because connectDatabase doesn't return anything so you implicitly get `None`, and the destroy returns `None`... and since `None & None` doesn't make sense... you get that error... What did/do you expect to happen?

Comment: What did you expect `connectDatabase` and `cManip.destroy` returns?

Answer (score 1):

`&` doesn't do what you think it does. It finds the the bitwise `and` of two objects. Instead, try defining the function:

```
 def function():
     connectDatabase(databaseEntry.get())
     cManip.destroy()

 entrySubmit = ttk.Button(cManip, text="Enter", width=20, command=function)
```

You could also replace the `&` with an `and`, which would work if the first function call does always only return `None` (or another false-valued value), **but this is a nasty, hacky, clever, and unreadable way of doing what you want** and will likely result in the confusion of you, and anyone reading your code.